# Custom wp_strip_all_tags() WordPress function

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to include line breaks on my WordPress excerpts.

To accomplish this, I see that I can change this function:

```
function wp_strip_all_tags($string, $remove_breaks = false) {
  $string = preg_replace( '@<(script|style)[^>]*?>.*?</\\1>@si', '', $string );
  $string = strip_tags($string);

  if ( $remove_breaks )
    $string = preg_replace('/[\r\n\t ]+/', ' ', $string);

  return trim( $string );
}
```

to:

```
function wp_strip_all_tags_breaks($string, $remove_breaks = false) {
  $string = preg_replace( '@<(script|style)[^>]*?>.*?</\\1>@si', '', $string );
  $string = strip_tags($string, '<p>');

  if ( $remove_breaks )
    $string = preg_replace('/[\r\n\t ]+/', ' ', $string);

  return trim( $string );
}
```

What is the best way to modify my theme to switch functions and provide this functionality?

Comment: Where does `wp_strip_all_tags` come from? It looks like it’s trying to sanitize HTML, but fails miserably at that…

Comment: It looks like it goes get_the_excerpt->wp_trim_excerpt->wp_trim_words->wp_strip_all_tags->strip_tags, where the excerpts lose their line breaks (wp-includes/default-filters.php & wp-includes/formatting.php).  I'm not seeing a better way to mod paragraphs back into get_the_excerpt without duplicating a bunch of code and throwing it all in my theme's functions.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding/overloading any of the WordPress core functions has to be done in the `functions.php` of your current theme.

First you have to define the new function in the `functions.php` (the name should be different from the original wpcore function name) and then you have remove the old function and add the new function to the respective hook/filter.

In case of `the_excerpt()` it should be done like this:

```
function new_function() {
    //code here
}

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'old_function');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'new_function');
```

Hope that makes sense.

EDIT: [Here](http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/improving-wordpress-the_excerpt/) is a good tutorial on how to edit `the_excerpt()` formatting.

Comment: Hmm, I had something along those lines in my text editor, but wasn't quite sure the minimal amount of tweaks necessary to add my one `,'<p>'` modification to the code.  Ideally, I only need to add about 6 characters to the existing code to get it to work.  I suppose I can copy/paste `wp_trim_excerpt()` to a new function that uses a modified `wp_trim_words()` (another copy/paste), that then uses my custom  `wp_strip_all_tags_breaks()` function (another copy/paste), then use the remove/add_filter on `get_the_excerpt` in the theme's functions.php file, but, that's a lot of redundancy.

Comment: So, I added this http://pastebin.com/yCHnrcsr to my theme's functions.php file.  Works, but, it looks pretty hacky.